# Schema version records become PENDING

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I have **DB dump** which already contains table **schema_version**. When I create **new database**, **add user** (used both for flyway auth and also as table owner in scripts), and then **restore DB**, I can run *flyway:migration* without problems.

If I **create user after database restore**, *flyway:migration* suddenly tries to create **new schema_version** table (*flyway:info* displays status `PENDING` for all records), which results in failure since DB already contains schema_version (from dump). What is the reason behind this? Isn't `PENDING` flag only for new scripts?

Comment: Can You provide exact table name in those two DBs? Flyway creates the table in `""` so in my case (I work on Oracle DB) I cannot select from `SCHEMA_VERSION`, I have to select from `"schema_version"`.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway couldn't find your schema history table. Make sure the configured schemas and table name match what you have in your database.

Comment: I'm using the default names, the only difference between the state when it is working and not working is steps: add user then restore DB vs restore DB then add user. Still don't understand what is the problem with the second one approach.